# Ctrl is not working in MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, myeclipse

I used to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on function's name and MyEclipse navigate me to its implementation, but since last week this option been disabled on MyEclipse. What should I do to enable it again?
[image]

And here is Hyperlinking:

[image]

Comment: How did you get your first screen shot, if the hyperlinking doesn't work? Do the links appear but don't do anything? I suggest you try a new, workspace (just specify a folder that doesn't exist, to get a new workspace) and import the project from your old workspace, just to check for workspace corruption issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore to default key bindings like this.

Go to Windows->Preferences->Type Keys.

In the keys dialog, restore to default by clicking "Restore Deaults" at the bottom.

Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` -> `Hyperlinking`.

Make sure that:

1. `Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation` checkbox is enabled.
2. `Default modifier key:` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
3. Appropriate `Link Kind` is checked and `Modifier Keys` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find #2 & #3

Comment: it is MyEclipse for Spring 2014

Comment: @Khodabakhsh MyEclipse is very different from Eclipse. You haven't mentioned that you're using it.

Comment: You are right, they are different in some cases. But in my case, how is that gonna get corrected?

Comment: @Khodabakhsh `Default modifier key:` is under `Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation` and `Link Kind` is in the table.